# ASP.NET MVC URI parameters naming

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working at an ASP.NET MVC Web Api controller, and I am just a beginner so maybe my question is quite trivial...

I'd like to take a parameter named `$filter` as input to my controller's method:

```
[Route("List")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult List([FromUri] string $filter = null)
{
    // ... code here ...

    return (Ok());
}
```

However I can't do like that, because `$filter` is not a valid C# variable name!

Anyway (due to customer requests) I really need to invoke that method passing `$filter=something` in the URI...

How can I do? Is there a method to "map" the naming of URI parameters, so that in code I can use the variable name `filter` (without the dollar) and then instructing the MVC layer to map `$filter` onto `filter`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `Name` property of `FromUriAttribute`:

```
[Route("List")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult List([FromUri(Name = "$filter")] string filter = null)
{
    // ... code here ...

    return (Ok());
}
```

Comment: Oh... what a stupid I am... it was sooooo easy. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. On a side note: You should change the requirement by communicating to your client this is bad practice ;) @MorixDev